# jQuery Encrypte Data

Tags: php, jquery

Actually my problem is ridiculous. I provide security by adding header. When I add the encrypted data, the browser gives an error.

Code source output :

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "���6���/��O��u�f�߁v2��",
},
```

[image: Console Output]

Browser detects:

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "���6���/��O��
u�f�߁v2��",
},
```

PHP Code :

```
 headers: {
     "Authorization": "<?php echo $_SESSION['sID']; ?>",
 },
```

My Session Class :

```
class Session {

    public function __construct() {
        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
        self::Encrypt('sID', session_id());
    }

    public static function Encrypt($Name, $Value) {
        if(!is_null($Value)) {
            $_SESSION[$Name] = openssl_encrypt($Value, Config::Get('Encrypt/Type'), Config::Get('Encrypt/Password'), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, Config::Get('Encrypt/Session'));
            return $_SESSION[$Encrypt];
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

What is the problem? Does anyone have an idea ? Best regards !

Also : `str_replace` and `trim` tried its functions.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `openssl_encrypt()` with the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag set will generally not be a printable string. It will usually contain invalid UTF-8 characters, and may sometimes include characters which will interfere with Javascript code parsing, like quotation marks.

Don't use the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag here. Without this flag set, the function will return Base64-encoded output, which is more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: base64 can be easily resolved. Do you have another suggestion? A good hacker can guess that he session_id.

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz It's not meant as a security measure. It's applied _after_ encryption to convert the encrypted data into a printable form.